# Removing Messages from iCloud (but not locally)

Tags: icloud, messages

How do I remove my Messages from iCloud **only**?

I want to keep them on my local devices (where I have plenty of space), but remove them from iCloud (where I'm low on space).

Answer (score 3):

First I would turn off Messages in iCloud.

You can turn off Messages in iCloud just for this Mac or for all devices where you use it.

Choose Messages > Preferences, click Accounts, then select iMessage in the Accounts list.

Deselect “Enable Messages in iCloud.”

Choose one of the following:

Disable All: Turns off Messages in iCloud for all your devices. Messages will no longer be stored in iCloud and will instead be stored on each device.

Disable This Device: Turns off Messages in iCloud for your Mac only.

Once that is done you can delete the messages in iCloud.

Comment: Ruskes: "Once that is done you can delete the messages in iCloud" -- How?

Comment: What if the device you enabled Messages in iCloud on is now lost/destroy and all your other devices never had "Enable Messages in iCloud" selected?  None of my devices has Messages in iCloud but I'm still being told that 6GB of my iCloud space is being taken up by messages.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem for many years. Can anyone tell me how did you "Removing Messages from iCloud (but not locally)". I need to free up space. Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/324890)